# CentOS: network adapter reset - error reading PHY register

Tags: networking, centos, nic

I have a problem with a server. The following is written in the /var/log/messages error log:

```
     Aug 15 10:22:46 s00000000 kernel: ------------[ cut here ]------------
     Aug 15 10:22:46 s00000000 kernel: WARNING: at net/sched/sch_generic.c:261 dev_watchdog+0x26d/0x280() (Tainted: G W ---------------- )
     Aug 15 10:22:46 s00000000 kernel: Hardware name: X9SCL/X9SCM
     Aug 15 10:22:46 s00000000 kernel: NETDEV WATCHDOG: eth0 (e1000e): transmit queue 0 timed out
     Aug 15 10:22:46 s00000000 kernel: Modules linked in: ip6t_REJECT nf_conntrack_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv6 xt_state nf_conntrack ip6table_filter ip6_tables ipv6 ext4 jbd2 serio_raw i2c_i801 i2c_core sg iTCO_wdt iT
     CO_vendor_support e1000e ext3 jbd mbcache raid1 sd_mod crc_t10dif ahci dm_mirror dm_region_hash dm_log dm_mod [last unloaded: scsi_wait_scan]
     Aug 15 10:22:46 s00000000 kernel: Pid: 0, comm: swapper Tainted: G W ---------------- 2.6.32-220.2.1.el6.x86_64 #1
     Aug 15 10:22:46 s00000000 kernel: Call Trace:
     Aug 15 10:22:46 s00000000 kernel: <IRQ> [<ffffffff81069997>] ? warn_slowpath_common+0x87/0xc0
     Aug 15 10:22:46 s00000000 kernel: [<ffffffff81069a86>] ? warn_slowpath_fmt+0x46/0x50
     Aug 15 10:22:46 s00000000 kernel: [<ffffffff8144a5fd>] ? dev_watchdog+0x26d/0x280
     Aug 15 10:22:46 s00000000 kernel: [<ffffffff8107c4a8>] ? add_timer_on+0xa8/0x120
     Aug 15 10:22:46 s00000000 kernel: [<ffffffff8144a390>] ? dev_watchdog+0x0/0x280
     Aug 15 10:22:46 s00000000 kernel: [<ffffffff8107c777>] ? run_timer_softirq+0x197/0x340
     Aug 15 10:22:46 s00000000 kernel: [<ffffffff810a0990>] ? tick_sched_timer+0x0/0xc0
     Aug 15 10:22:46 s00000000 kernel: [<ffffffff8102ad2d>] ? lapic_next_event+0x1d/0x30
     Aug 15 10:22:46 s00000000 kernel: [<ffffffff81071f81>] ? __do_softirq+0xc1/0x1d0
     Aug 15 10:22:46 s00000000 kernel: [<ffffffff81095590>] ? hrtimer_interrupt+0x140/0x250
     Aug 15 10:22:46 s00000000 kernel: [<ffffffff8100c24c>] ? call_softirq+0x1c/0x30
     Aug 15 10:22:46 s00000000 kernel: [<ffffffff8100de85>] ? do_softirq+0x65/0xa0
     Aug 15 10:22:46 s00000000 kernel: [<ffffffff81071d65>] ? irq_exit+0x85/0x90
     Aug 15 10:22:46 s00000000 kernel: [<ffffffff814f4ec0>] ? smp_apic_timer_interrupt+0x70/0x9b
     Aug 15 10:22:46 s00000000 kernel: [<ffffffff8100bc13>] ? apic_timer_interrupt+0x13/0x20
     Aug 15 10:22:46 s00000000 kernel: <EOI> [<ffffffff812c4ade>] ? intel_idle+0xde/0x170
     Aug 15 10:22:46 s00000000 kernel: [<ffffffff812c4ac1>] ? intel_idle+0xc1/0x170
     Aug 15 10:22:46 s00000000 kernel: [<ffffffff81097a8d>] ? sched_clock_cpu+0xcd/0x110
     Aug 15 10:22:46 s00000000 kernel: [<ffffffff813f9ff7>] ? cpuidle_idle_call+0xa7/0x140
     Aug 15 10:22:46 s00000000 kernel: [<ffffffff81009e06>] ? cpu_idle+0xb6/0x110
     Aug 15 10:22:46 s00000000 kernel: [<ffffffff814e5fbb>] ? start_secondary+0x202/0x245
     Aug 15 10:22:46 s00000000 kernel: ---[ end trace 7b02a6494611efa0 ]---
     Aug 15 10:22:46 s00000000 kernel: e1000e 0000:02:00.0: eth0: Reset adapter
     Aug 15 10:22:46 s00000000 kernel: e1000e 0000:02:00.0: eth0: Error reading PHY register
     Aug 15 10:22:46 s00000000 kernel: e1000e: eth0 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: Rx/Tx
```

For some reason, CentOS wants to reset the network adapter and has then a problem with reading the PHY register, thus the network fails completely. I have to restart the server then.
I've done some google searching of course. I found some identical reports but no solution.

The problem occurs very irregular, the last time before today was two weeks ago.

Anyone got an idea?

Answer (score 0):

The NETDEV WATCHDOG message means the NIC stopped sending data given to it. Why the NIC stopped respoding is unclear.

This problem is currently being worked on upstream within Red Hat, though there is no solution yet.

You might be better to see if there's an existing thread or bug within the CentOS project and report there, the CentOS team can then collect relevant information and supply it to Red Hat for further troubleshooting.